# How can I fix "The emulator process was killed" error in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm working on an android app so I tried to download android emulator to debug and develop the app.
When I tried to run the emulator I got this error which I couldn't fix:

[image: The error in android studio]

Just to clarify: I did download and install sdk tools if that helps.

any suggestion?
thanks in advance